# MongoDB - Comparing speed of queries between shard vs no shard

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections named user and user_no_shard.

user collection contains 1 million documents located in shard_0 and 1 million documents located in shard_1

user_no_shard collection contains 1 million documents located in shard_0

I use "find" command for those collections. It consumes **6 mins for finding all documents of user collection** and **3 mins for finding all documents of user_no_shard collection**.

In theory, the time for two queries is the equivalent. But it was not equivalent.

Help to explain please!

Comment: Do both collections have the same indexes? Use `db.user.getIndexes()` to find it. Also, when you do the query, take a look to the `explain` function, i.e.: `db.collections.find({<your_query>}).explain()`. You will see how mongo performs the query, whether it uses indexes and how and more: see: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/

Answer (score 1):

The user collection contains 1 million documents located in shard_0 and 1 million documents located in shard_1. It Means a total of 2 million documents exist in user collection and only 1 million documents in user_no_shard collection. It is not appropriate to compare in this scenario.

Have 2 million documents in user_no_shard collection and comparing with user collection would be appropriate.

With Sharding configured appropriately , mongodb chooses appropriate shard to proceed collection scan skipping one half of documents to be scanned.

Comment: You mean that mongo sequentially scans shards, NOT concurrent? So the partition of documents of collection doesn't improve speed of query?